# problem in creating a non standard link list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I finished learning object oriented programming (basics only) and started to learn link list and I got to know it consists of nodes which consists of data and a pointer to next node.

In the following code, I have tried to create 5 objects of class node , each of which has two attributes - data and pointer to other object. I tried to attach nodes using a function attach as shown. And in the end , I intend to recursively print the data from last node i.e. arr[4] to first node i.e. arr[0]. Since only the first node has a null pointer in its attribute next, idea was that the recursion would stop at first node. But , the output shows that arr[4] has a null pointer in it's member next.
I'm not able to find where am I going wrong.

> Input : 4 3 2 1 0
>
> Output : 4
>
> Output that I expect : 0 1 2 3 4

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node
{   public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};
void attach(node &s1,node &s2)
{
    s1.next=&s2;
}
void print(node &source)
{
    cout<<source.data<<" ";
    if(source.next)         return; 
    else                    print (*(source.next));
}
int main()
{
    int n{5};
    node arr[n];
    cin>>arr[0].data;
    arr[0].next=nullptr;
    for(int a=1;a<n;++a)
    {
        cin>>arr[a].data;
        attach(arr[a],arr[a-1]);
    }
    print (arr[4]);
}
```

Comment: `if(source.next) ` has the condition reversed.  It should be `if(!source.next)` or the more explicit `if(source.next == nullptr)`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for pointing that out. I made a stupid mistake.

Comment: Less stupid than many. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @user4581301 that's very kind of you.